# Prevent authors from creating new posts of specific custom-post-type

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles

The way I'm set up currently, I create a post for each user of the site, custom-post-type, Agent, then assign it to a user, and they can edit it however they like. What I want to remove or disable is in the admin side, Agents/Add New.

Currently all users are set to Author, so if I could make it so if the user is an Author they can't create new posts of custom-post-type, Agent.

I'd also like to remove the ability of the author to create standard wordpress posts.

The caveat to all this is I need to allow authors to create as many posts as they like as custom-post-type, Property.

Here is a pic of what I want to remove (in red) for agents custom-post-type, if the user is an author.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try my plugin [**Posts Creation Limits**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bainternet-posts-creation-limits/) which was made for that same reason.

Comment: I added an image to my original question, will it remove the items I've outlined? Thanks

Comment: @Chuck No but even if its shown you wont have a problem and you can simply hide it `<style>.button add-new-h2{display: none;}</style>` The dropdown will be removed by WordPress core at 3.2 and I'll add that to my plugin soon